# I can't load images and fonts into my package (Java)

Tags: java, embedded-resource

I would like to use personal fonts and images in java but since I am using a package it cannot find the images and fonts, do you have a specific method of accessing these resources ?

```
        //FONT
    this.lblStatut = new JLabel("C’est au tour du seigneur Noir ! =^∇^*=", JLabel.CENTER);
    this.lblSubtitle = new JLabel("Choisissez la planète à conquérir ou libérer.", JLabel.CENTER);
    String fName = "./assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf";
    String f2Name = "./assets/fonts/FreePixel.ttf";
    InputStream fFont = PanelStatutNoir.class.getResourceAsStream(fName);
    InputStream f2Font = PanelStatutNoir.class.getResourceAsStream(f2Name);
    try {
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fFont);
        Font bigFont = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 45);
        Font font2 = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, f2Font);
        Font smallFont = font2.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 16);
        
        this.lblStatut.setFont(bigFont);
        this.lblStatut.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        this.lblSubtitle.setFont(smallFont);
        this.lblSubtitle.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    catch (IOException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (FontFormatException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

    //Rectangle
    this.imgFond = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage( "assets/msgStatut/Rectangle.png" );
```

Comment: Did you take the [tour]? Did you [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+getresource) for similar questions? It appears that you are incorrectly [accessing resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html).

Comment: The fact you did not include the package name of the class, nor the 'file structure' of the project means we cannot tell definitively what those strings should be but, but try removing the `.` from the prefix of the first two and adding `/` as prefix to the string without one. In future, post a [mre] & show the project structure. Voting to close.

Comment: The name of the package is not important, what i am asking is a specific method to access images which are in a folder with my java files, while the classes are compiled in the package_class, i dont know how to do that.

Comment: *"The name of the package is not important.."* It is when using ***relative* paths** like all 3 of those strings are! What on Earth do you think the 'relative' part means? *"what i am asking is a .. method to access images which are in a folder with my java files"* By 'folder' (which is a GUI term) I figure you mean 'directory' (the underlying part of a file system that might be seen as a 'folder' in an OS that is graphical). Don't put resources in with Java source code files! Extra files in that path will *not* be copied to the build directory. Put them instead under a `resources` directory.